# Django NoReverseMatch error - urls.py path appears to match

Tags: python, django

In a Django application I am building as a project for an online course, I am expecting a link in one template (entry.html) to direct to a path ("edit") in urls.py with a variable in the url. This should initiate a function called edit in views.py and render the template edit.html.

I am getting a NoReverseMatch error (`"Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P<entry>[^/]+)/edit$']"`) after clicking the link in entry.html. If I view page source while on entry.html in the development server, I can see the url matches that in urls.py but I still get this error.

In the example below, "maggie" is the value for `entryTitle` I'm trying to pass.

**entry.html:**

```
{% block title %}
    {{ entryTitle }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{ entry|safe }}

    <button>
        <a href="{% url 'edit' entry=entryTitle %}">Edit Entry</a>
    </button>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py (last path listed is `edit`)**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("new", views.new_page, name="new"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>/edit", views.edit, name="edit")
]
```

**edit function in views.py**
also displaying my `entry` function

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(),
        label="Edit Content:")

def edit(request, entry):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Edit file and redirect
        form = EditPageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            util.save_entry(entry, content)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('entry', kwargs={'entry': entry}))
    else:
        #Load form with initial values filled
        content = util.get_entry(entry)
        form = EditPageForm(initial={"content": content})
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "editform": form,
            "entryTitle": entry
        })

def entry(request, entry):
    markdowner = Markdown()
    entryPage = util.get_entry(entry)
    if entryPage is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/notfound.html", {
            "entryTitle": entry
                      })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdowner.convert(entryPage),
            "entryTitle": entry
        })
```

Is anyone able to see what is causing this error with my code? I am surprised because when viewing page source, it seems that `{% url 'edit entry=entryTitle %}` is being correctly interpreted as `wiki/maggie/edit` , which is present in urls.py with `maggie` as `<str:entry>` and yet I am getting this error.

Here is a screenshot of page source:
[image]

Comment: `1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<entry>[^/]+)/edit$']` That doesn't seem to match the urls.py file you posted...

Comment: You are passing in the value ```maggie``` into the url string, not as a parameter to the django view. Either remove the ```entry``` from your view definition, ``def edit(request)``` or add an extra pass to your views ```path("wiki/<str:entry>/edit/<str:entry>", views.edit, name="edit")```. (Untested).  As of now its looking for an ```edit``` view that doesn't have an argument, which is not defined.

Comment: Sorry I had been trying with a without the leading "wiki/" and posted the wrong error message. I corrected my post with the error message I received just now, with the .html and .py files as shown

Comment: The problem is the same. Django is looking for a function of ```edit``` without any parameters (accept request which is assumed). This is because you're not passing any parameters to it. To test, remove entry from edit ```def edit(request): print('im here')``` and see if it prints. If you need to pass entry to your view, change url as I mentioned above.

Comment: @sintribu I tried changing the url as suggested and got an error in my terminal when running ```python3 manage.py runserver``` which reads: ```re.error: redefinition of group name 'entry' as group 2; was group 1 at position 32```.

Comment: @sintribu Also I am confused because I have another function ```entry``` in views.py that uses part of the url string from the ```entry``` path in its function and that seems to work fine? I added the code to question above

Comment: @AB-89v1 See my answer and let me know I can add any clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my previous answer, my apologies. You should make your life easy and restructure your url

```
path('wiki/edit/<str:entry>', views.edit, name="edit")
```

```
<button href="{% url 'edit' entry=entryTitle %}"></button>
```

This should work.

The previous way was:

```
path('wiki/<str:entry>/edit', views.edit, name="edit')
```

I get the error message:

```
Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'entry': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['so/wiki/(?P<entry>[^/]+)/edit$']
```

I'm not sure why, but its something to do with it being an object, because passing in a hardcoded string `"maggie"` instead of `entryTitle` works fine. Sorry for all the confusion.